# Ansible copy file

Tags: ansible

How can I copy a file from machine A to machine B and machine C on different location.
ie:

On machine A I have file abc and I want to copy it on the /tmp area of machine B and /op area of machine C

Comment: When you honored the encapsulation of tasks in roles it should be easy to define the path as variable and hand it set it as host variable in the playbook under host_vars. See [Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html "Playbooks") for general Information, especally Playbook Roles and Include Statements. After that, read [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html "Best Practices") for a deeper understanding.

Comment: I tried to map the destination path with the machine on inventory file but didn't know how to use it on playbook.  ie:

 cat ansible_hosts
[webserver]
sm-niraj dst=/home/niraj
vl-sm dst=/tmp

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an inventory that was structured something like this:

```
[remote-servers]
192.168.X.1
192.168.X.10
192.168.X.20
192.168.X.30
```

ran the following copy task:

```
- name: copy the file to the remote machine
  hosts: remote-servers
  copy:
    src: /path/to/file
    dest: /path/to/dest
```

Comment: Thanks. But what would be the procedure if destination path is different for all the machines.(In my case destination path is different on all the machines)

Comment: In my case: On machine A I have file "abc" and I want to copy it on the "/tmp" area of machine B and "/opt" area of machine C

Comment: is there both hosts have same OS ?

Comment: It may be or may not be but would be fine if you provide me the solution for any condition. Thanks in advance and appreciate your effort to take a look into this.

Comment: you have to write two different tasks with when condition which copy at different locations.
when condition for check current remote host's ip address.
you can get current remote host's ip address using :-

hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']

or 

hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv6']['address']

Comment: That's fine but it's good for only 1-2 remote server and in my condition I have around 100 machines and on each machine I need to copy it on different location :(
For that i need to write 100 tasks , right ?

Comment: Yes, You are right to full fill you requirement you have to write 100 tasks.
ansible supports jinja2 may be that will helpful for you to do this task.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh , will give a try to jinja2